# How to automatically transfer folder(or file) from USB to PC with autorun?

Tags: usb, file-transfer, autorun

I'm trying to create simple command that will automatically copy specific folder from USB when its pluged in to desktop.

Comment: Autorun has been disabled by default since WinXP

Comment: You also don't want to re-enable autorun if there's even the slightest chance you'll plug in either your USB-drive that has seen someone else's computer, or someone else's usb-drive altogether. What exactly is your goal here? Maybe there are other solutions.